# How to add EditText programmatically?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

How to add **EditText** programmatically?

Here's what I wrote:

```
View RV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__dummy,container, false);

LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
EditText ET = new EditText(getActivity());
ET.setId(5);
ET.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LL.addView(ET);

return RV;
```

Thank You!

Comment: can you post your logcat error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                EditText edttext= new EditText(this);
                edttext.setId("edittext");
                edttext.setLayoutParams(params);

            layout.addView(edttext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `LinearLayout LL` dynamically too.

You need to add it to `RV` like

```
((ViewGroup)RV).addView(LL);
```

Also you should set the `LayoutParams` for `LL` too

Comment: Something like?

``View RV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__dummy,container, false);
LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) RV .findViewById(R.id.LL1);
LinearLayout(getActivity());
LL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
EditText ET = new EditText(getActivity());
ET.setId(5);
ET.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
((ViewGroup)RV).addView(LL);
return RV;``

Comment: Like `((ViewGroup)RV).addView(LL);`